# nginx DNS over TLS proxy IP transparency

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, ssl

I currently have nginx set up to forward DNS over TLS requests to my private local DNS server with the following configuration:

```
stream {
    upstream dns-servers {
        server    127.0.0.1:53;
    }

    server {
        listen 853 ssl;
        proxy_pass dns-servers;
        ssl_preread on;

        ssl_certificate            cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key        key.pem;
        ssl_dhparam                ssl-dhparams.pem;

        ssl_protocols        TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers          HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        ssl_handshake_timeout    10s;
        ssl_session_cache        shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout      4h;
    }
}
```

This works fine but the DNS server see all of the requests as coming from `localhost`. So I would like to also forward the source IP addres to my DNS server.

I've tried adding

```
proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
```

and also tried adding

```
proxy_protocol on;
```

but after adding them I get the following error in the logs:

```
2019/09/25 14:48:40 [error] 26463#26463: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while proxying connection, client: <remote ip was here>, server: 0.0.0.0:853, upstream: "127.0.0.1:53", bytes from/to client:1040/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0
```

Comment: Isn't `proxy_bind` sufficient? `proxy_protocol` is for enabling the PROXY protocol which adds data before proxying the stream and as such, needs to be actively supported by the upstream.

Comment: Yes, since reading up on it the proxy_protocol does need to be supported by the upstream server. This is currently not the case for my setup. 

I have found this guide from ngnix : https://www.nginx.com/blog/ip-transparency-direct-server-return-nginx-plus-transparent-proxy/

but I have not been able to successfully set up a transparent proxy. I think two separate servers are needed for IP transparency to work - a proxy and upstream on different machines.

Has anyone been successful in setting up the proxy and upstream on the same server?